# How can I use Oculus Rift as monitor?

Tags: oculus

Although not completely a programming related question, I need this information acquired to progress in the development of a game that is not run through the Oculus Rift, but rather run normally on as an application on the screen featuring the two "eye holes".

I have got the full release of Oculus, not one of the development kits. From what I've read and understood, these mirrored the screen by default, the full version does not. The full version from what I've heard instead uses its own driver for displaying graphics, not actually visible on the screen.

What I would like to do, is switch over so that I can see the screen through Oculus. How would one go about doing this?

Should you feel this question is not on topic under the Stack Overflow community, do tell where this should be posted. I do feel however that programmers are very right for the nature of this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What I would like to do, is switch over so that I can see the screen through Oculus. How would one go about doing this?

There are a number of applications that do things along these lines, including SteamVR, and Virtual Desktop, and Envelop VR.

> From what I've read and understood, these mirrored the screen by default, the full version does not.

At no point has the Rift actually acted to mirror what's on screen.  What you may be referring to is that previous development kits, when plugged in, would be visible to the operating system as just another monitor.  However, anything that was on this monitor (windows, backgrounds, etc) was not actually usable, because the Rift display is divided in half, so each eye would see *part* of a *distorted* half of the screen.  Completely unusable as a 'monitor replacement'.

> Should you feel this question is not on topic under the Stack Overflow community, do tell where this should be posted.

Probably [SuperUser](https://superuser.com/), or alternatively a [proposed VR specific stack exchange](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/90074/virtual-and-augmented-reality).

> I do feel however that programmers are very right for the nature of this question.

Lots of questions are useful to software developers, but not specific to them.  This site is for questions specific to software developers.

Answer (score 0):

You want the [Virtual Desktop](http://store.steampowered.com/app/382110/?l=polish) app.